# Display Eclipse tabs on several lines

Tags: eclipse, ide, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-3.5

I'm using eclipse galileo. Is it possible to display the tabs of my open files on several lines instead of using the `>>` sign. I still want a unique window to view the code though.

If there is no such settings, do any plugin exists ?

Comment: I have been following this Eclipse bug for years now. The eclipse team seems to be totally against this feature. I think it is a travesty to have someone ELSE tell me how I should like my UI. If every one of the 11K people who have seen this question would vote for the bug, then the Eclipse team would have no choice but to implement it due to popular demand. Don't be sheeple people!!! VOTE FOR THE BUG!!!!!!!

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=58945

Comment: If the eclipse team is against the feature and because of that the don't implement it, I believe they are misunderstanding what "satisfying the client" means. Usually this kind of attitude reveals an authoritarian way of thinking. I don't know if that's the case for the team. Too bad if it is. I've been working with multiple lines for years, and it has been helping me A LOT.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

No.

[Bug 58945: CTabFolder should support multi row and vertical style options](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=58945), opened since 2004! ([other bugs](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg42093.html) exist on the same topic)
(**Update Feb. 2017**: it seems to be assigned, with [Oxygen 4.7](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Oxygen) as target!
Thank you [specializt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/351861/specializt) for mentioning that [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059690/display-eclipse-tabs-on-several-lines/3063469?noredirect=1#comment72029700_3063469))

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> is one workaround for now.

Other "workarounds" are [listed in this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools/msg46375.html):

- turn on the "close editors automatically" option (preferences > General > editors), which will close editors automatically when the limit is reached an a new editor is to be opened.
- make use of multiple windows each with a set of editors for areas you are editing or browsing or searching
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to close all tabs quickly

---

As mention by [Big Chair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1972372/big-chair) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059690/display-eclipse-tabs-on-several-lines/3063469?noredirect=1#comment35868965_3063469):

> Someone made a workaround here: "[Eclipse multiple tab rows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9502736/6309)"

[Wes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/918077/wes) explains:

> I've discovered that while it is true that you **cannot** have multiple rows of tabs for the same code-space, **it is possible to have multiple rows of tabs showing on your window at the same time**:
>
> To accomplish this, **simply drag a tab up to your title bar and release. It will create another row of tabs**.

Comment: Ok, so that sounds like a definitive no. Sadly none of these workarounds are near to the behaviour I'm looking for.

Comment: @DrDo: I understand. You have here a long debate on the tabs in Eclipse, worth reading: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=68684#c27

Comment: Someone please implement this feature, oh god why. Are we really as bad as to deserve this?

Comment: @Big_Chair good point. I have included the workaround in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: I have been following that bug for years now.  The eclipse team seems to be totally against this feature.  I think it is a travesty to have someone ELSE tell me how I should like my UI.  If every one of the 11K people who have seen this question would vote for the bug, then the Eclipse team would have no choice but to implement it due to popular demand.  Don't be sheeple people!!! VOTE FOR THE BUG!!!!!!!

Comment: it finally is ASSIGNED and will probably be released sometime! Yes! Eclipse finally gets basic editor functionality!!

Comment: @specializt Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: The bug has gotten an update this year. Someone actually did some work on it.

Answer (score 37):

ctrl+shift+e gives a nice dialog with all open windows.
ctrl+e gives the "quick" version of this dialog.

Answer (score 3):

I found this plugin, which lists all open windows in a separate tab, and lets you open windows with a single click:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/editorviewer/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is neither such setting nor plug-in (at least freely available). But if there is, I'd like to be corrected.

Answer (score 0):

The Open-Editor  plugin does it. But it has issue.