# Eclipse multiple tab rows

Tags: java, c++, eclipse

Is it possible to have multiple rows of tabs in Eclipse?

I haven't been able to find a setting anywhere in the application.  I'm currently running the Galileo version.

Comment: I also noticed Eclipse displays the tab list in the order of opening, therefore making it largely chaotic (not respecting the tab order in the editor titlebar)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I've discovered that while it is true that you **cannot** have multiple rows of tabs for the same code-space, it **is possible** to have multiple rows of tabs showing on your window at the same time:

[image: eclipse multiple tab rows]

To accomplish this, simply drag a tab up to your title bar and release.  It will create another row of tabs.

I generally like to keep my 'main' files on one tab and my reference files on another.  Of course to switch from one tab row to another and see the code, requires you to drag the separator up and down.

I like this workaround and it is better than nothing for now (at least until there is a fix released).

Comment: Could you please clarify, how did you make it. Dragging a tab to a title bar didn't help.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I understood, you've created 2 editors. Actually, you can make as much editors as you like and you can place them not only vertically but horizontally too. And each of them will have it's own "tabs row".

Comment: You can drag a tab to bottom, right or left (and probably not up!) to create another editor.

Comment: Great idea, from number of days I thought about this. Thank you so much

Answer (score 30):

No, it is not possible.

If you have too many file opened in Eclipse (too many tabs), maybe two keyboard shortcuts could help:

- **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>**
  Shows a list of editors.
- **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>**
  Shows a list of editors next to the tabs (like clicking the double arrow next to the tabs)

Comment: Or possibly have 2+ windows opened -best with 2+ screens-

Comment: `Ctrl+E` is also a useful shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

I was also interested by this question and found an alternative. I share it for whoever is interested.
EditorList for Eclipse : http://editorlist.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on Juno, at least not for me.

Comment: `EditorList` causes numerous interface errors for me in `eclipse-cpp-juno-SR2-linux-gtk-x86_64`, i.e. Eclipse Platform 4.2.2. In contrast, `EditorViewer_0.1.6.jar` works, but is a bit slow.

Comment: released : 2005. Any questions? This plugin was made back when dinosaurs still used eclipse.