# How to increase number of tabs in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

How to increase number of tabs representing opened document (file) on top of the main window or expand tab panel on 2 or more lines like the bottom panel in Windows in Eclipse? Its very annoying to search for tab every time because only 5 tabs displaying by default...

Comment: What's your screen resolution? I see a lot more then 5 opened tabs...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display Eclipse tabs on several lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059690/display-eclipse-tabs-on-several-lines)

Comment: Here is another - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8297293/eclipse-multiple-tab-rows with a workaround...